Regularity structures-paracontrolled distributions: do they always work for sub-critical SPDE?
Stochastic PDE could be solved using either regularity structures or paracontrolled distributions, as long it's sub-critical.
I was wondering if this was proven, that is every sub-critical SPDE could be solved using regularity structure or paracontrolled distributions, if so what is the general form of SPDE that are covered?
For example, consider the following stochastic wave equation: $$\partial_{rr}u=\Delta u+u^2+\xi,$$ $\xi$ is a space-time white noise, the critical dimension is $7,$ sub-critical if $d \leq 6,$ I know that $d=2,3$ were solved using paracontrolled distributions, can we still solve the equation for $d=4,5,6,$ since these cases are all sub-critical?
regularity structures-paracontrolled distributions involve constructing (renormalization and proving convergence) ill-defined terms, is there a general "machinery" for all SPDE?

For a black box theorem the treats the whole subcritical regime in the regularity structures framework see the article "Renormalising SPDEs in regularity structures" in JEMS by Bruned, Chandra, Chevyrev, and Hairer. In principle, such results can also be done in the paracontrolled approach but I don't know if it has been followed through completely. See the work of Bailleul and Bernicot "High order paracontrolled calculus". Finally, note that the RG approach initiated by Kupiainen can also handle the...

...whole subcritical regime, as shown by Duch  in https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.11380
